# Resizing and compressing AJAX images in Node/AngularJS application

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization, image-processing, angularjs

I'm building an app in AngularJS, built on Node/ExpressJS. I have a list of images which are hosted externally (and I have no access to them to compress them at the source).

The issue is, that often these images are quite large - ~200kb for a 600x600 image. I don't want to serve such large files to my users, especially those on mobile with data caps and whatnot.

Is there any service (or Node module) which would allow a middleman-style way of compressing the images that AngularJS serves up to the user? Something like [`Google PageSpeed Service`](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service) (a surprising number of people haven't heard of this, check it out, it's awesome) would be absolutely perfect, except it doesn't work with AJAX images/AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

You have services like http://kraken.io/ - It is just a matter of hooking a url pattern to an API call for the optimized image. The problem with such services is that they aren't scalable (at least cheaply), since you are using third party bandwidth and processing power.

I would strongly advice caching the files somehow, on your side of things, though. Or even do it the other way around - hook the optimizing to changes to the image list, and serve the optimized files from your end.

Doing this from angular is doing this from each user's computer: with a limit of 50 files/day lasting (apparently) 1 hour on their server, you'll quickly run out of API calls.